# What kind of instrument is a horn?

Tags: dnd-5e, equipment

What type of real world musical instrument would a horn from the musical instrument table in the Player's Handbook correspond to?

Answer (score 10):

### It's exactly the kind of horn you're likely picturing in your head.

Ultimately, this kind of question is best handled between a player and their DM, as the type of horn will need to be consistent with the world they're in, the level of technology, and the player's backstory.

Wikipedia entry: [Horn (Instrument)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horn_(instrument))

[image]

Comment: There are pictures in the DMG for magic items where the horns generally look like this, I can't recall a page however.

Answer (score 5):

Musical instruments in the horn category evolved from, like the picture, hollowed out horns. Now they're mostly made of brass. Trumpets, bugles, french horns (it's in the name!), trombones, baritones, tubas, etc. are all horns.

Medieval horns, fantasy gaming type instruments, are probably more like bugles, or trumpets. But if it doesn't break your immersion for your Bard to play the trombone or flugelhorn, throw on some Chuck Mangione and go to town.

Comment: Hi Steve, and welcome to RPG Stack Exchange. Check out our [tour] when you can to get across the details of how we work here. When you reach 20 reputation you can also join us in [chat].

Comment: Fellow Nerd Poker listener?

Answer (score 0):

A blunt one. Unless you use the pointy end. Then its a pointed weapon. That is what you're using your instrument for, right? Otherwise you're doing it wrong.